# What does spit mean in "spit in my glove" from the memoir by Powers? Literally spit?

Tags: meaning, essays, katherine-a-powers

An excerpt from ["My Glove"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44363340?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) by Katherine A. Powers:

> I walked around (out of sight of the house) with the glove tucked under my arm, wishing I could shove it in my back pocket like boys did in books, but of course my pants, when I was allowed to wear pants, had no pockets because my mother had made them. I wished I knew where to get neat’s-foot oil, not available at Woolworth’s, but no one I could confide in knew anything about that. Another thing I could not do, I might as well confess, **was spit in my glove.** I could direct the occasional **spitting** noise at the pocket, yes. But shoot **a gob of spit** right in there and work it in like you read about? No, I couldn’t.

I don't believe "spit" is literally spit, which doesn't make sense to me. So what's the meaning beneath?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning is literally 'spit':

> Spitting for baseball players is like blinking; it's going to be a tough habit to break. It's not even just spitting on the ground. You know, a lot of us have routines and habits — you know, you spit a little bit in your glove before a pitch. It's got to be a conscious effort from everyone. And, you know, we're going to have to do our best.
> [The Current](https://www.cbc.ca/radio/thecurrent/the-current-for-july-22-2020-1.5658469/spitting-is-part-of-baseball-tradition-and-will-be-tough-to-quit-historian-says-1.5658473)

> Saliva is also used as a lubricant to break in a stiff new baseball glove. Though studies prove that the practice is bad for the glove, both pros and amateurs continue to spit into their glove to soften the leather.
> [The Indian Express](https://indianexpress.com/article/explained/explained-why-a-ban-on-spitting-is-tough-to-swallow-for-baseball-players-6496036/)